# How can I ng-click a function from my angular-js directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I cant figure how to call a function from my directive using ng-click.

This is an example of my HTML:

```
 <div>
    <directive-name data="exemple">
        <button class=btn btn-primary type="submit" ng-click="search()">
    </directive-name>
</div>
```

This is an example of my javascript :

```
...
.directive('directiveName', ['exempleService', function(exempleService) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.search = function() {
            console.log("this is working")
        };
    };

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {data:'=',
        search:'&'}
    }

}]);
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `directive` which includes the `button` inside the directive template (either as HTML or external file).

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <directive-name data="exemple"></directive-name>
</div>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.directive('directiveName', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.search = function() {
        alert('boe');
      }
    },
    template: '<button class=btn btn-primary type="submit" ng-click="search()">CLICK</button>'

  }
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ujwhxdow/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be in your directive template

```
.directive('directiveName', ['exempleService', function(exempleService) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.search = function() {
            console.log("this is working")
        };
    };

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><button class=btn btn-primary type="submit" ng-click="search()"></div>'
        scope: {data:'=',
        search:'&'}
    }

}]);
```